# Multi Rectangles Positions fix for Customized Stickers Printing in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an implementation where we need 6 blocks for sticker printing in a page. 
The position is to be fixed for each rectangle as attached:
[theReportLayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVrca.png) .
I have used 6 different parameterized datasets for each tabllix and kept that in each of the rectangle respectively and based on parameters the visibility is handled.
But when only one parameter is selected for e.g., the 4th one  is selected the rectangle is displayed at position 1 with slight downwards.
Same goes with any one selection which is an issue.
I need the position fixed for whichever single or multi selection is used.
Please suggest.
Thanks in advance
Sunny.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that when you say you need the positions fixed, that you want all six rectangles to stay in those positions regardless of what parameters are selected. Try putting all 6 rectangles in a parent rectangle to fix the locations on the report.

Comment: Yes , Finley its correct , but am not able to implement the same in rdl file.

Comment: @SunilKumar I'm assuming that you are using Report Builder, is this correct? Implementing it directly through a text editor may be difficult.